# No timestamps in Watson speech-to-text

Tags: node.js, npm, text-to-speech, ibm-watson

I'm using the Watson-Developer-Cloud module, following along with the example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/watson-developer-cloud#speech-to-text

Unfortunately none of my options seem to be working:

```
timestamps: true, profanity_filter: false, word_confidence:true
```

Am I passing them in at the right place?

```
var watson = require('watson-developer-cloud');
var fs = require('fs');

var speech_to_text = watson.speech_to_text({
  url: "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api",
  username: 'xxxxx',
  password: 'xxxxx',
  version: 'v1'
});


fs.createReadStream('./resources/speech.wav')
  .pipe(speech_to_text.createRecognizeStream({ content_type: 'audio/l16; rate=44100', timestamps: true, profanity_filter: false, word_confidence:true }))
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./transcription2.txt'));
```

I'm getting back the transcript but I'd like the timestamps and the confidence score.  This is a sample of what I'm getting back:

> "five phone calls away from having a great **** week"

As you can see, no timestamps, no confidence score, and profanity is still filtered.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at the recognise stream events for more control over the output, for example:

```
// Create the stream.
var recognizeStream = speech_to_text.createRecognizeStream(params);

// Pipe in the audio.
fs.createReadStream('audio-file.wav').pipe(recognizeStream);

// Pipe out the transcription to a file.
recognizeStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('transcription.txt'));

// Get strings instead of buffers from 'data' events.
recognizeStream.setEncoding('utf8');

// Listen for events.
recognizeStream.on('data', function(event) { onEvent('Data:', event); });
recognizeStream.on('results', function(event) { onEvent('Results:', event); });
recognizeStream.on('error', function(event) { onEvent('Error:', event); });
recognizeStream.on('close-connection', function(event) { onEvent('Close:', event); });

// Displays events on the console.
function onEvent(name, event) {
    console.log(name, JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
};
```

The [API documentation](http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/speech-to-text/api/v1/?node#recognize_audio_websockets) has an example too.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help.  I got the correct output from 'recognizeStream.on('results', function(event) { onEvent('Results:', event); });'

But I don't quite understand the recognizeStream.pipe api.  How would I write results to the file instead of data?

Comment: In your event handler you would just use Node.js function `fs.writeFile(file, data[, options], callback)`. See https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback for details